# Python program works in shell but in console

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, shell, django-models

I'm writing a program that enables my Django application to consume a REST API. My problem is that Django rejects the program if I run it as a `.py` file, but accepts it via shell. The program is divided into two files: one that interacts with the API, and another that interacts with Django. The main folder structure is as follows:

```
/root folder
  [rest of Django project]
  -__init__.py
  -test.py
  -mid_side.py
  -teamup_api/
    -__init__.py
    -teamup.py
```

where `test.py` is the file that starts the program, `mid_side.py` is the Django-side part, and `teamup.py` is the API-side part. Below is the specific code I'm having trouble with.

**test.py**

```
import django
from mid_side import dates
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime(2017,7,28)
end = datetime(2017,8,19)
test = dates(start,end)
print(test)
```

Where `dates` is a method from `mid_side` that accepts two `datetime` objects as parameters.

According to Django, the problem emerges in `mid_side.py`, as it imports models from an app in the main Django project. The specific line Django has issues with is `from events.models import Service`, where `events` is an app Django uses and `Services` is a model. The traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mid_side import dates
  File "/home/brian/Github/nydkc11/nydkcd11/mid_side.py", line 3, in <module>
    from events.models import Service 
  File "/home/brian/Github/nydkc11/nydkcd11/events/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from embed_video.fields import EmbedVideoField
  File "/home/brian/anaconda3/envs/server/lib/python3.6/site-packages/embed_video/fields.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .backends import detect_backend, UnknownIdException, \
  File "/home/brian/anaconda3/envs/server/lib/python3.6/site-packages/embed_video/backends.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .settings import EMBED_VIDEO_BACKENDS, EMBED_VIDEO_TIMEOUT, \
  File "/home/brian/anaconda3/envs/server/lib/python3.6/site-packages/embed_video/settings.py", line 7, in <module>
    'embed_video.backends.SoundCloudBackend',
  File "/home/brian/anaconda3/envs/server/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/brian/anaconda3/envs/server/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting EMBED_VIDEO_BACKENDS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I know for a fact the traceback concerns an app my project uses, [django-embed-video](https://github.com/jazzband/django-embed-video). What I don't understand is why Django is indicating it as a problem considering a) `Service` doesn't use fields from `django-embed-video`, b) I successfully deployed the application on my project earlier. My questions are thus as follows:

1) **Why does this problem occur in the `.py` file and not in shell?**

2) **What is causing Django to output the traceback?**

Below is relevant code from the program. Please notify me if additional clarifications are required. Thank you!

*I decided not to include `teamup.py` as this is more of a Django-side problem, but I will include it if requested.

**mid_side.py**

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from events.models import Service
import datetime
from teamup_api.teamup import *
def dates(start,end):
    event_list = day_query(start.year, start.month, start.day, end.year, end.month, end.day)['events']
    service_objects = []
    for event in event_list:
        service_objects.append(Service(
            title=event['title'],
            school=none_parse(event['who']),
            location=none_parse(event['location']),
            start_time=parse(event['start_dt']),
            end_time=parse(event['end_dt']),
            all_day=event['all_day'],
            description=none_parse(event['notes'])
        ))
    return service_objects
```

**models.py**

```
class Service(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    all_day = models.BooleanField()
    description = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

---

UPDATE: I've been running 'shell' through `manage.py shell`, and 'console' via natively running a python file (e.g. `python [file].py`)

Comment: What do you mean by "shell", and how is that different from "console"? Do you mean `manage.py shell`?

Comment: Yeah, as `manage.py shell`. For console, I tried running it as `python [file].py`

Comment: The whole point of `manage.py shell` (vs. simply running `python`) is to wire up all of the Django infrastructure. Normally I would build any CLI tool as a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/); you'd then run it via `manage.py`, e.g. `python manage.py my_custom_command arg1 arg2`. Is that an option for you?

Comment: It would probably suffice for development, but my concern is deploying the program in production, as I have to eventually set up a chrontab job that automatically runs the program at a certain time of day, and that would probably require having a runnably `.py` file.

Comment: It certainly does _not_ "require having a runnable `.py` file". Simply run `/path/to/python /path/to/manage.py subcommand arg1 arg2` from `cron`. You'll probably want your `python` executable to come from whatever virtualenv you're using for the project.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was probably that I was using Django resources in the native `python` environment. As Chris indicates in the comments, creating a [custom `manage.py` command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/) instead of a `.py` start file should suffice.